# What happen to files deleted using the Jupyter Notebook interface?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have a large .zarr folder of about 800GB. Deleting using the `rm -r` command takes several hours and slow the machine down to a crawl. If I instead navigate to that directory and delete it using the Jupyter Notebook interface (version 6.5.2), then the deletion is instantaneous. I read that Jupyter Notebook do not delete the files, rather, it is moved to the trash - occupying the same amount of disk space. I checked `.local/share/Trash/files` and found some, but not all, of the files I deleted over the last few months. The recently delete .zarr folder was NOT in there.

I want to make sure that the file is properly deleted and the disk space is made available. If the file is gone, how can Jupyter notebook delete the file so much faster than the `rm -r` command. If the file is simply moved, what other location could it be located? I didn't note the available disk space prior to the deletion so I have no idea if any was made available. The disk is also hundreds of TB in size so searching for a specific file through all the directories will take ages.